# Multiple prefixes in RestEasy configuration

Tags: java, jersey, resteasy

I am using Jboss RestEasy web services, and I need to multiple url to map to that web service. Is there any possibility that I can set multiple prefixes for 'resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefixconfigured

here is my configuration in web.xml

```
 <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servletclass>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping> 

      <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
      </context-param>
```

I want service for both "/rest" and "/service" prefixes

Answer (score 5):

For a quick test, I changed your `<context-param>` into `<init-param>` inside `<servlet>` and in RESTeasy 3.0.5 it worked for me.

So a workaround might be to define two servlets with the same configuration and differing only on `resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix` value of `<init-param>`'s, and define two mappings for them.

Beware that now you have *two* servlets that live their own lives (e.g. separate contexts and lifecycles), which might be unacceptable in some scenarios.

**UPDATE:** Also take a look at this answer, similar to mine although more elaborated (I haven't tried it myself): https://stackoverflow.com/a/25487574/283519

Answer (score 1):

@pwes Thanks a lot!
I was looking to expose two RESTful services. 
Say /api1 and /api2 . 
Your suggestion works for both what the OP wants and what I wanted too.

Here's how each servelet is configured:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>entity-manager</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/api1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Second one:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>entity-manager</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/api2</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: @MatthewGreen - What you're correct with your comment's content, I feel this answer could actually add some value. Sometimes it's very handy to have an example of exactly how to use some code.

Comment: My intention is not only to thank you. But if someone else gets stuck configuring multiple REST APIs like me, I thought this answer would help. Since "multiple services RESTEasy" has this in the top 5 results.