# Multiple endpoints with Resteasy

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have two separate handfuls of REST services in one application. Let's say a main "people" service and a secondary "management" service. What I want is to expose them in separate paths on the server. I am using JAX-RS, RESTEasy and Spring.

Example:

```
@Path("/people")
public interface PeopleService {
  // Stuff
}

@Path("/management")
public interface ManagementService {
  // Stuff
}
```

In `web.xml` I *currently* have the following set-up:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/public</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `PeopleService` and `ManagementService` implementations are just Spring beans.
Above `web.xml` configuration will expose them both on `/public` (so having `/public/people` and `/public/management` respectively).

What I want to accomplish is to expose the `PeopleService` on `/public`, so that the full path would become `/public/people` and expose the `ManagementService` on `/internal`, so that its full path would become `/internal/management`.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the value of the `@Path` annotation.

How should I do that?

Comment: Why you can't modify the path annotation? you don't have access to the code?  as far as I can see they are interfaces, do you have access to the implementations?

Answer (score 16):

actually you can. After few hours of debugging I came up with this:

1) Declare multiple resteasy servlets in your `web.xml` (two in my case)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/openrest</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.rest.PublicService</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>private-resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/protectedrest</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.rest.PrivateService</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>private-resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/protectedrest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>      

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/openrest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Please pay attention to the fact that we initialize personal `resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix` and `resteasy.resources` for each our servlet.
Please don't forget to **NOT** include any botstrap classes as filters or servlets! And disable autoscan as well.

2) Create a filter that cleans up application from the RESTeasy's global information that it saves in context:

```
public class ResteasyCleanupFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        request.getServletContext().setAttribute(ResteasyProviderFactory.class.getName(), null);
        request.getServletContext().setAttribute(Dispatcher.class.getName(), null);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);


    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Register it for any request to your services (here I used it for all requests for simplisity):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CleanupFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mycompany.ResteasyCleanupFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CleanupFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Thats it!Now you have two different REST services which lays under different prefixes : `/openrest` which meant to service all public requests and `/protectedrest` that takes care about all the private stuff in the app.

So why does it work (or why it does not work otherwise)?

When you call `openrest` instance for the first time it tries to initalize itself and when done saves the state in the global `servletContext` like this :

```
 servletContext.setAttribute(ResteasyProviderFactory.class.getName(), deployment.getProviderFactory());
 servletContext.setAttribute(Dispatcher.class.getName(), deployment.getDispatcher());
```

And if you will let it be your call to your second `/protectedrest` will get the SAME configuration! That is why you need to clean up this information some where. That is why we used our `CleanupFilter` which empty the context so brand new rest servlet could initialize itself with all the init parameters we declared.

This is a hack, but it does the trick.

This solution was tested for RESTEasy *2.3.6*

**EDITED**

Works with 3.0.9.final as well!

Comment: Anton, thanks for taking the time to figure this out! It really helped me! @pbean, I opened a [bug request](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1312) for this, on the JBoss issue tracker.

Comment: (Plus one) for at least testing. More than I can say for most people that answer questions :-)

Comment: Really good explanation. My contribution for your post is: the method `request.getServletContext()` only works with a container that supports Servlet 3.0.

Comment: For older Servlet API you can get ServletContext in a Filter as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10623024/292628)

Comment: Someone knows how use this configuration with Swagger? I'm trying to generate a different swagger.json for each endpoint, but i'm having problems like this: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2099

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you cannot have multiple servlet mappins for your JAX-RS implementation. 
What you could do is: map RESTEasy to `'/'` (or `'/api'` for example if your application has other resources to serve and you don't want the JAX-RS part to interfere), then have the following `@Path` annotations:

```
@Path("/public/people")
public interface PeopleService {
  // Stuff
}

@Path("/internal/management")
public interface ManagementService {
  // Stuff
}
```