# Multiple Prefixes for RestEasy services

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I need to have multiple prefixes in my RestEasy project. For the same, I have defined multiple servlets as below in `web.xml`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest1</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.rs.TokenGenerator</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest2</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.rs.ResourceProvider</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.test.rs.filter.AuthFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest2/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The same approach is defined in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687251/multiple-endpoints-with-resteasy/25487574), but 
I haven't got it working in my project yet. I always get back `404 Not Found` error when trying to access the URLs below. Can anyone highlight what I am missing in the configuration?

> http://localhost:8080/rstest/rest1/token
>
> http://localhost:8080/rstest/rest2/resource

The web context root of the project deployed is `rstest`

My class has the `@Path` annotation defined as below

```
@Path("/token")
public class TokenGenerator {
```